# Content cut on the right in a responsive design

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm re-creating a YouTube page using media query.
However, when I change the size of the browser, I find that on the right side, some content is always cut.
I used grid for the blocks.
I tried to set some margin in body, but it didn't work.

Since I couldn't upload the entire code, I re-created the problem.
My code is below

The image shows what I mean.
[image: content partially hiding on the right]

```css
.thumbnail-1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.video-info-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
}

.video-info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}

.thumbnail-row {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.video-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 16px;
  row-gap: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .video-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1199px) and (max-width: 801px) {
  .video-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .video-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .video-info {
    width: 350px;
  }
  .video-title {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
  .video-author,
  .video-stats {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="video-grid">
  <div class="video-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail-row">
      <img class="thumbnail-1" src="images/thumbnail-2.webp" />
    </div>

    <div class="video-info-grid">
      <div class="channel-picture"></div>
      <div class="video-info"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail-row">
      <img class="thumbnail-1" src="images/thumbnail-2.webp" />
    </div>

    <div class="video-info-grid">
      <div class="channel-picture"></div>
      <div class="video-info"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail-row">
      <img class="thumbnail-1" src="images/thumbnail-2.webp" />
    </div>

    <div class="video-info-grid">
      <div class="channel-picture"></div>
      <div class="video-info"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail-row">
      <img class="thumbnail-1" src="images/thumbnail-2.webp" />
    </div>

    <div class="video-info-grid">
      <div class="channel-picture"></div>
      <div class="video-info"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please put your html and css code for this section

Comment: Hi, I just did. Please let me know if you need other snippets. Thank you!

Comment: Look at the code snippet I just made from your posted code and ask yourself: "does this accurately recreate my problem?" I - personally - don't think that it does. If you agree with me, then please edit the snippet to include enough of your "*[mcve]*" code (HTML and CSS) to reproduce your problem. The *minimum* amount of code, **not** "all of your code."

Comment: @LixinLi you put a code that doesn't show nothing make a simple example of your problem that we can help you

Comment: @Mohamad I just uploaded a simple example. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidThomas I just did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code like this and tell me if it's work for you

```css
.thumbnail-1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.video-info-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
}

.video-info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}

.thumbnail-row {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

.video-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(300px, 100%), 1fr));
  column-gap: 16px;
  row-gap: 40px;
}



@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .video-info {
    width: 350px;
  }
  .video-title {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
  .video-author,
  .video-stats {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="video-grid">
  <div class="video-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail-row">
      <img class="thumbnail-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </div>

    <div class="video-info-grid">
      <div class="channel-picture"></div>
      <div class="video-info"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail-row">
      <img class="thumbnail-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </div>

    <div class="video-info-grid">
      <div class="channel-picture"></div>
      <div class="video-info"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail-row">
      <img class="thumbnail-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </div>

    <div class="video-info-grid">
      <div class="channel-picture"></div>
      <div class="video-info"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail-row">
      <img class="thumbnail-1" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </div>

    <div class="video-info-grid">
      <div class="channel-picture"></div>
      <div class="video-info"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```